# In-spite of calling asp.net button click event by jquery why my page refreshed(post to server)

Tags: jquery, asp.net

My concept is when I click an ASP.Net button then it's run on server and the page is refreshed. So we use jQuery to run an ASP.Net control on the client side.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default4.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default4" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#Button1").click(function () {
                    var a = $("#TextBox1").val();
                    if (a > 5)
                        $("#mydiv").text(a + ' is greater then 5')
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
                <div id="mydiv"></div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works fine but the message which is generated by this code, `$("#mydiv").text(a + ' is greater then 5')` is not remaining in the page because the page is refreshed.

My question is in spite of calling button click by jQuery why is my page refreshed and why is the message is not remaining in the page?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is with your current code you are adding a new handler to the button click event but are not preventing the default handler by the asp.net framework, the default handler will create a postback so click event can be processed on the server side.

You have some options here, the first one is if you dont need to proccess the click event server side (code behind), consider using a simple input element:

```
<input type="button" value="Button" id="Button1" />
```

If you really need to use a server control, you can either stop the button from raising a postback by doing:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return false;" />
```

Or better you can use onclientclick property to call your client functions without the jquery click bind something like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return doSomeStuff();" />
```

using the following javascript code:

```
function doSomeStuff(){
  var a = $("#TextBox1").val();
  if (a > 5)
    $("#mydiv").text(a + ' is greater then 5')
  return false; //needed to stop the postback
}
```

Comment: If this answer helped, please mark it as an answer by clicking the check